# Subtract tax from a price with tax in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, calculation, tax

How do I subtract all taxes from a price *with* tax in OpenCart?

In the example below I use the default "Taxable goods" tax setting from OpenCart, which is 20% VAT + $2,00 Eco-Tax.

```
$number = 20.80

// Get $number tax:
$tax = $this->tax->getTax( $number , $product_info['tax_class_id'] , $this->config->get('config_tax') );

// Subtract tax from total price:
$result = $this->currency->format( ( $number - $tax ) , $this->session->data['currency'] );
```

This returns an incorrect value of $14,64 because it calculates the tax on `$number` (20,80), which already is a price *with* tax. The correct price for $20,80 without tax should be $15,67

This should be the formula in this case:
(20.80 - 2.00) / 120 * 100 = 15.6667

Is there any way to subtract all taxes from a price that already has tax included?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wish I did, but unfortunately no.

Comment: Yes, but only in this example. The prices and tax rates are variable. If I use OpenCarts methods for calculating tax (as in the example code) the returned value is incorrect.

Comment: The tax is not always 20% as store owners around the world have different tax rates. If I calculate 20% tax and $2,00 eco-tax but a store owner in another country has set different tax rates, the calculation is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$taxRate = 20;

$gross = 150;
$divisor = (100 + $taxRate) / 100;
$net = round( $gross / $divisor, 2);
$tax = round( $gross - $net, 2 );

Echo "Gross was $gross - Net is $net Tax is $tax";
```

RESULT with 20% tax

```
Gross was 150 - Net is 133.33 Tax is 16.67
```

RESULT with 15% tax

```
Gross was 150 - Net is 130.43 Tax is 19.57
```

Try a few dry runs and then check with this code

Answer (score 0):

if your tax for example is 21% and you have product with tax=120.. Without tax will be: 120/1.21.
so if Tax rate:

```
$tax_rate = 21;
```

product price:

```
$price = 120;
```

Price without tax:

```
$price_without_tax = $price/($tax_rate/100 +1);
```